# Typescript - Error when importing React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am migrating my React `.js` files to `.tsx` files and stumbled upon this issue. Here is a bare-bone example of the problem.

**ParentComponent.tsx**

```
import MyCustomComponent from './MyCustomComponent';

export class ParentComponent extends React.Component<{customText: string}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <MyCustomComponent customText={this.props.customText} />
        );
    }
}
```

**MyCustomComponent.tsx**

```
export const MyCustomComponent = ({ customText }: { customText : string }) => (
    customText != null && customText.length > 0 &&
    <tr>
        <td colSpan={12} className={"somecssclass"}>
            <div className={"somecssclass2"}>
                {customText}
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
);
```

There is a red underline on the `<MyCustomComponent ... />` line with the following errors:

> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   ./src/app/MyComponent.tsx:78:37
>       TS2605: JSX element type 'false | Element' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.   Type 'false' is not assignable to type
>   'ElementClass'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   ./src/app/MyComponent.tsx:78:37
>       TS2607: JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   ./src/app/MyComponent.tsx:78:52
>       TS2339: Property 'customText' does not exist on type '{}'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `customText != null && customText.length > 0 && ...` will return `false` if both conditions are not true. What happens if you write `customText != null && customText.length > 0 ? <tr> ... </tr> : null` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`customText != null && customText.length > 0 && ...` will return `false` if both conditions are not `true`, which TypeScript interprets as invalid JSX.

You can instead explicitly return `null` if both conditions are not `true`, and it will work:

```
export const MyCustomComponent = ({ customText }: { customText: string }) => (
  customText != null && customText.length > 0 ? (
    <tr>
      <td colSpan={12} className={"somecssclass"}>
        <div className={"somecssclass2"}>{customText}</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ) : null
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked. Is adding the ternary the only way to get around this? In our project, we're using a lot of React's conditional rendering using the `&&` operator (e.g. `someCheck && <someComponent>`)

Comment: @noblerare I'm not sure to be honest. I have not found another way around it myself. I also like to use `&&` when using React with just JavaScript, but haven't found a way to do it in TypeScript.